# How to create Twilio call answer group

Tags: twilio

Iam using Taskrouter in my project.

All works fine. My agents are using the javascript client to receive calls.
I want if the first agent don't answer, it rings the second, then third and then to voicemail while
caller hears music and waiting for next available agent.

This is my configuration:

incoming-call.php

```
`<?php
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
?>

<Response>
  <Gather action="enqueue-call.php" numDigits="1" timeout="5">
    <Say voice="Polly.Joanna-Neural" language="en-us">Thank you for calling ABC incorporated Customer Support.</Say>
    <Say voice="Polly.Joanna-Neural" language="en-us">Your call may be monitored or recorded for quality assurance.</Say>       
    <Say language="en-us" voice="Polly.Joanna-Neural">For English, please hold or press one.</Say>
    <Say language="es-us" voice="Polly.Joanna-Neural">Para Espan~ol oprime el dos.</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>`
```

enqueue-call.php

```
`<?php

$digit_pressed = $_REQUEST['Digits'];

if ($digit_pressed == '1') {
  $language = "en";
} else {
  $language = "en";
}

$wfSid = 'WW.......';
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");

?>

<Response>
  <Enqueue workflowSid="<?php echo $wfSid; ?>">
    <Task>{"selected_language": "<?php echo $language ?>"}</Task>
  </Enqueue>
</Response>
`
```

answer-call.php

```
`<?php

            $assignment_instruction = ['instruction'=>'dequeue','post_work_activity_sid'=>'WA......','from'=>'1800.......'];        
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($assignment_instruction); 

 ?>`
```

Comment: Task Router will work great if you can use it to determine worker availability (this is built-in). Can you build an interface to allow an agent to sign-in and mark themselves as "available" for a call? If so, your desired workflow will be easy to implement. Taskrouter will route a call to an available agent and if none are available it will route to voicemail (or keep the caller on hold). Controlling availability for a call center workforce by whether an agent answers their phone is not a typical inbound call center workflow.

Comment: I do allow the agents to mark themselves Available or Unavailable. I just wanted to control the number of rings to each agent and number of agents before voicemail. Ex. Agent 1 gets 3 rings, bounce to Agent 2, 3 rings, and last perhaps Agent 3.

Comment: You can't control the exact number of rings but you can set the number of seconds using the timeout parameter: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#timeout